# warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
  json: 1.8.6
  ruby: 2.7.2
  rails: 6.0.3.6
```

I am frequently getting the following error in my application

```
 /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
```

When I searched for this error I got a solution i.e., I need to update my json gem version but here I have many other dependencies on the json-1.8.6 version, So I cannot update the gem. When I update the code in common.rb file explicitly.

```
 def parse(source, opts = {})
    Parser.new(source, opts).parse
 end
```

I have updated above code as follows

```
def parse(source, opts = {})
  Parser.new(source, **opts).parse
end
```

It is working without any errors but I think it is not the correct way to disable the warning.

Comment: Adding the `**` is okay but doing it by hand in the installed `common.rb` is not. You really should upgrade the JSON gem and fix up everything that depends on that specific version, 1.8.6 is pretty old and the sooner you bring things up to date the better. If you absolutely cannot update the gem right now then you'd be better off forking it at version 1.8.6, patching the fork, and then updating your `Gemfile` to use your forked version; this is a temporary hack though, not a proper way forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

config/initializers/json.rb

```
 module JSON
   module_function

   def parse(source, opts = {})
     Parser.new(source, **opts).parse
   end
 end
```

Comment: Still some times I am getting the warning like when I start the rails server / console / sidekiq. In all other situations, warnings were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the particular gem that gives the warning.
Do so manually - check the gem website and update the gemfile, then do `bundle update`. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the gem yomu was requiring json 1.8.6. Removed this gem and warnings went away (of course I have json ~> 2)

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem at hand. This is a workaround.